# How to build a static library in eclipse on osx

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

What i did so far as an experiment:

1. file -- new c++ project -- static library -- empty project -- LLVM with Clang (osx)
2. create two files: addnum.cpp and addnum.h
3. build project

File content:

addnum.cpp:

```
int addnum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

addnum.h:

```
#ifndef ADDNUM_H_
#define ADDNUM_H_


int addnum(int, int);


#endif /* ADDNUM_H_ */
```

After building I have a file named addnum.bc in the Debug/ folder. What I was expecting was a libaddnum.a file. Why is it not there?

Platform: OSX 10.9
Eclipse version: 4.4 Luna

I have also tried the same thing on a Ubuntu 10.04 machine and got the same result.

Comment: If its holding you up, it might be easier to compile: `clang++ addnum.cpp -c`: then create the archive: `libtool -static -o libaddnum.a addnum.o`; and finally, generate the index: `ranlib libaddnum.a`. You can stuff it in a makefile to quickly build in the future.

Comment: where do I put the makefile in eclipse?

Comment: I am just thinking using a hand-made makefile defeats the whole purpose of using an modern IDE, :-/

Comment: This might help: [CDT Importing an Existing Managed Make Project Tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_import.htm).